# Search movie trailers with youtube api and angular

Tags: angular, rest, youtube

After searching, here on stackoverflow and in the API documentation, I can't figure out how I'm going to search for a movie trailer in youtube with a variable. I have this method in my service URL:

```
getTrailer(): Observable<Object> {
    let url =
     ' https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=guy&key=(mykey)'
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
      map(res => {
        return res['items'];
      })
    );
  }
```

And back in the component subscription I can see this items array, but Im failing to understand how to fetch a trailer video according to an users input...Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the query parameters, they are explained here 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A25%2C%22q%22%3A%22surfing%22%7D

First of all I would use the `topicId=/m/02vxn` (Movies).
And add `q=trailer` as term.

That ends up in a request url like this

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=trailer&topicId=%2Fm%2F02vxn&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```